# Windows 10 - someone changed login to Microsoft instead of local user

Tags: windows, windows-10, login

My stepdaughter got onto my wife's computer and changed the login to microsoft account, and of course cannot remember the password.  the login screen only shows the one "new" microsoft account and the local account which was used previously isn't available to login.

How can I force windows to boot from the local account?  Help!!!!!!

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, because I'm not (yet) providing details on how to login w/ that MS acct's password.  I suspect how this happened: My guess is Microsoft Cortana.  I had that software switch my login type, without fully realizing that it would affect the entire Windows 10 login.  (I since read that Microsoft made related updates to Win 10.)  Then I left the computer idle and the "screensaver" locked my system, requiring the Microsoft login.  I fixed the issue by looking up my password.  This [password reset](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=242000) might help.

Comment: This is one [of the many]  reasons you don't give people access to your own account. That's what limited accounts are for, so an inexperienced user can't mess things up. I hope @TOOGAM 's link helps, but I'd also take it as a lesson learned.

Comment: trust me, I'm well aware that inexperienced users shouldn't have that type of access.  She knew her mothers password and wasn't using the account she was supposed to.  Her mother is furious so going forward i know this won't be an issue.

Comment: Microsoft says that I can't provide enough info to reset account.  funny thing is that I can login to Office 365 with the micorsoft login and password and it works just fine.  somehow it appears that the password on the computer isn't the same as the one to login to microsoft.

Comment: is there any way to reboot the computer and by hitting a key or key-combination force it back to local account mode?  I'm sure this is something that occurs (like losing access to the MS Account) often and that MS has a recovery option for.

Comment: Michael: Sadly (for your case), I don't think so.  If this is anything like prior Windows versions, if you press Ctrl-Alt-Delete and lock the system (which is what I think has effectively been done already), you ought to be able to log into another account on the system.  But I think the switch from local account to a corresponding Microsoft account has an effect similar to disabling the local account that made the switch.  I doubt you'll be able to use that local account to rectify before you log in successfully.  Although, if you have *another* local account to log in with...  *(maybe?)*

Comment: I'm surprised nobody mentioned [Kon-Boot](http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/) yet. It's what computer technicians use to access your account when you forget to give them the administrator password. It's not free but it works. You boot into Windows using the Kon-Boot bootable CD/USB and you'll see a new user called kon-boot at the welcome screen with administrative access.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to log in to your account and only after change it to "local account". 
Microsoft provide a function for Microsoft account user to recover forgotten Microsoft account password:

https://account.live.com/password/reset

If you cannot retreive it by this way, you can always put the dvd back in and use the console to retreive it, for example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dfEd4HZyV4

Some softwares can even erase the password but it can be tricky...

Comment: I'm able to login to O365 with the credentials, but they do not work when trying to login to windows 10. The procedure used in the youtube video seems pretty simple - will it work for O365 accounts as well on the PC?